# Through Excel modify the line spacing in a Word Document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have this excel file which I have been able to write the data into a Word document through vba for a report. The VBA code is within the excel file containing the data.

I already have most of the code done and it is working properly, but I can not figure out how to tell word (through the vba code in excel) to change the paragraph spacing. Any advice?

I am using the following code to write into word from excel(not the full code just an example):

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
wdDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Test"
wdDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
wdDoc.SaveAs (file & "\SpecificReport_" & filter & ".doc")
wdDoc.Close
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendation, but not specific answer. If you have any trouble figuring out how to do something from Excel with Word, i find that recording actions in word and reviewing the code generated usually answers that for me.

In this specific instance I came up with the following lines of code:

`wdDoc.Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6`
`wdDoc.Content.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBeforeAuto = False`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have been asked to change the normal font back to single spacing (pre-word2010). Apart from altering the normal.dotx try this:

```
With The_WordDoc.Styles("Normal").ParagraphFormat
.SpaceBefore = 0
.SpaceBeforeAuto = False
.SpaceAfter = 0
.SpaceAfterAuto = False
.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle

End With
The_WordDoc.Styles("Normal").NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = _
  False
With The_WordDoc.Styles("Normal")
  .AutomaticallyUpdate = False
  .BaseStyle = ""
  .NextParagraphStyle = "Normal"
End With
```